# Как при наследовании заставить переопределить метод базового класса

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Как заставить обязательно переопределить метод .virtual позволяет переопределить , но не заставляет , этот вариант не подходит

Comment: `abstract` *(4 символа нужно...)*

Comment: `abstract`? а лучше приведите пример, что у вас конкретно не получается

Comment: Ну и хак вида throw new NotImplementedException() (или другое подходящее) в virtual методе при первом же запуске заставит.

Comment: @vitidev, может не заставить, если метод нигде не вызывается :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант с помощью наследования от interface
2. Вариант с помощью наследования от abstract class и в нём абстрактный метод

Лучше в данном случае пожалуй использовать interface, учитывая что вам нужно 100% переопределять.